# With Matrix blocks how can i get the column names

Tags: matrix

From a craft matrix block how do i get the field names when no data has yet been entered?

i can write:

```
$o_matrix_block->getContent()->getAttributeConfigs();
```

this will give me an array:

```
 Array
                    (
                        [id] => Array
                            (
                                [maxLength] => 11
                                [min] => -2147483648
                                [max] => 2147483647
                                [decimals] => 0
                                [type] => number
                                [unsigned] => 
                                [length] => 10
                                [column] => integer
                            )

                        [elementId] => Array
                            (
                                [maxLength] => 11
                                [min] => -2147483648
                                [max] => 2147483647
                                [decimals] => 0
                                [type] => number
                                [unsigned] => 
                                [length] => 10
                                [column] => integer
                            )

                        [locale] => Array
                            (
                                [column] => locale
                                [default] => en_gb
                                [type] => locale
                            )

                        [title] => Array
                            (
                                [required] => 
                                [maxLength] => 255
                                [label] => Title
                                [type] => string
                            )
```

but I only get the array, when I have entered data.

with out getcontent() but the array elements are wrong

Pls help!

:)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the array is empty because there is no content.
Try `$o_matrix_block->getType()->getFields();`

Answer (score 1):

my genius colleague found the answer, this will print out the matrix field column names.

```
$o_user_model = craft()->userSession->getUser(); // Get current user

$o_matrix_block_type_model = craft()->matrix->getBlockTypeById(5);

$a_fields = $o_matrix_block_type_model->getFieldLayout()->getFields();

foreach($a_fields as $o_field_layout_field_model) {

    $o_field = $o_field_layout_field_model->getField();
    var_dump($o_field->handle);  
}

die;
```